# Getting new area of map revealed after scrolling. LARAVEL GOOGLE MAPS V3

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps-api-3, eloquent, laravel-5

I trying to make efficient queries to show markers on google maps.  I need to show many markers, which are stored in a MYSQL database.

I am getting them back through AJAX, and linking it to the 'idle' event listener on the map to make a query and only make markers for the newly revealed area, and not for any part of it that is already showing.

I am doing this by posting the old bounds and the new bounds to server, and there I am writing queries with these values. I am trying to keep track of the bounds of the map, using map.getBounds() but having some logic issues..

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    var mapBounds = map.getBounds();
    var ne = mapBounds.getNorthEast(); // LatLng of the north-east corner
    var sw = mapBounds.getSouthWest();
    var oldBounds = {
        'minLat' : minLat,
        'maxLat' : maxLat,
        'minLng' : minLng,
        'maxLng' : maxLng
    };
    minLat = sw.lat();
    maxLat = ne.lat();
    minLng = ne.lng();
    maxLng = sw.lng();

    // console.log(minLat + ' - ' + maxLat + ' - ' + minLng + ' - ' + maxLng )
    var newBounds = {
        'minLat' : minLat,
        'maxLat' : maxLat,
        'minLng' : minLng,
        'maxLng' : maxLng
    };

    // if this condition is true, than I will make trip to server via AJAX
    if(newBounds.minLat < oldBounds.minLat || newBounds.minLng > oldBounds.minLng || firstRun)
```

Is there a google maps method I may have overlooked? Is this how you would ahve to do it?

Here is the controller method that is attempting to get only spots in the newly revealed area, its close but behaves strangely sometimes.

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    if($request->oldBounds['minLat'] == '') {
        //properties oldbounds accessed via array values...
        return Spot::where('latitude', '>', $request->newBounds['minLat'])
            ->where('latitude', '<', $request->newBounds['maxLat'])
            ->where('longitude', '<', $request->newBounds['minLng'])
            ->where('longitude', '>', $request->newBounds['maxLng'])->get();
    }

    // but also in the new bounds of the map...
    $bottom = Spot::where('latitude', '<', $request->oldBounds['minLat'])
                ->where('latitude', '>', $request->newBounds['minLat'])
                ->where('longitude', '<', $request->newBounds['minLng'])
                ->where('longitude', '>', $request->newBounds['maxLng'])->get()->toArray();

    $top = Spot::where('latitude', '>', $request->oldBounds['maxLat'])
            ->where('latitude', '<', $request->newBounds['maxLat'])
            ->where('longitude', '<', $request->newBounds['minLng'])
            ->where('longitude', '>', $request->newBounds['maxLng'])->get()->toArray();

    // but also in the new bounds of the map
    // these arent working properly... :(
    $right = Spot::where('longitude', '>', $request->oldBounds['minLng'])
        ->where('longitude', '<', $request->newBounds['minLng'])->get()->toArray();

    $left = Spot::where('longitude', '<', $request->oldBounds['maxLng'])
        ->where('longitude', '>', $request->newBounds['maxLng'])->get()->toArray();

    $spots = $right + $left; //+ $right;
    return $spots;
```

Any pointers? Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Matt

Comment: I think part of my problem was the way I was putting the arrays together. Should be $spots  = array_merge_recursive($top, $bottom, $left, $right);